# Multiple picture boxes in multiple tab pages

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, managed

I have one tabcontrol on a form with two tabpages and two picture boxes in each. I use rightclick to open a context menu for selecting a file to display in each picturebox. When I do it with one picturebox it is OK. However, after selecting a file for other picturebox fails with an exception "Parameter not valid".

Basically, I do this:

```
System::Void DPrint::Form1::toolStripMenuItem1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
    {
        if (imgToDisplay != nullptr)
        {
            delete imgToDisplay;
        }

        PictureBox^ MyPictureBox = safe_cast<PictureBox^>(this->contextMenuStrip2->SourceControl);

        imgToDisplay = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(this->openFileDialog1->FileName);
        MyPictureBox->Image = safe_cast<Image^>(imgToDisplay);

    }
}
```

Any idea what is wrong? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
I was deleting the last image to be displayed so I have removed an if statement
and everything works. Thank you.